# Import error when importing wx

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython

When I try to import wx, I get an error saying:

```
File "C:\...\__init.py__", line 14, in <module>
import __version__
ImportError: No Module  names __version__
```

I went into **init.py** and lines 14 and 15 are:

```
import __version__
__version__ = __version__.VERSION_STRING
```

I am using Python 3.4
and the wx I installed was

```
wxPython3.0-win32-py27  32-bit Python 2.7
```

Is this an issue with backward compatibility or with the installation?

Comment: Yeah that is your issue. You will want to use Python 2.7 when working with wxPython

Comment: The 3.0 is the version of the wrapped wxWidgets. There is the Project Phoenix (http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix) that implements wxPython for Python 3. However, there is no official release version, yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `wxPython3.0-win32-py27` then you have to install python v2.7
Check the wxPython's [official page](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

you should install python 2.7. there is no wxpython package for python 3.0 and above...